# Java: find classes with certain base type on program startup

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader

I have a `Java` program (an `Eclipse plug-in` to be specific), which is using several `JAR` files (which I can control). One of the core `JAR` files defines an `abstract class` called **Strategy**. When the user starts the program, the program needs to know all sub classes of **Strategy**, that are on the program `ClassPath`.

As I described in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287749/java-use-static-initializer-blocks-to-register-classes-to-global-static-registr), I tried to use static initializer blocks on the sub classes, so that they auto-register themselves in a registry. This approach is not working since the static initalizers are not executed before I explicitly use the class.

Is there any other way to find all classes with a certain base type that are on the current `ClassPath`?

I can think of the following solutions:

- traverse all `JAR`s in a specific directory and check the classes they contain
- create a file which is loaded on program start-up and read the class names from that

I can implement both of them myself (so I do not ask for any code samples here). I merely want to know if there is another option I am missing. Any in-class solution (like the one I tried with static initializers) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.eclecticlogic.com/2014/09/01/classpath-scanning/

Comment: The https://code.google.com/p/reflections/ library offers this (classpath based) with a method `getSubTypesOf`

Comment: Search the web for examples or help with the Eclipse JDT interfaces `IType` and `ITypeHierarchy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to using a third-party library, [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) seems to be the best fit here. It's a Java runtime metadata analysis library and is like geared to do this. From their website:

> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types/constructos/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, optionally with annotation parameters matching
> - get all resources matching matching a regular expression
> - get all methods with specific signature including parameters, parameter annotations and return type

All you need is to create a configured instance of `Reflections` in your `StrategyRegistrar` class as

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.your.app.strategies.pkg"))
           .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner())
       );
```

And, then simply fire a query like

```
Set<Class<? extends Strategy>> strategies =
    reflections.getSubTypesOf(com.your.app.strategies.pkg.Strategy.class);
```

Comment: Reflections projects looks very interesting. I would have just dropped down to the JDK APIs, but this looks neater. Thanks for sharing this!