# How to implement a static extensible registry in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was trying to implement a static registry that can be extended by 3rd party developers adding their items to this registry, again, statically.

I am running into the problem described at [Java: use static initializer blocks to register classes to global static registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287749/java-use-static-initializer-blocks-to-register-classes-to-global-static-registr) - however, the suggestion described there to have a *Registrar* that registers each class does not fit my requirements since the 3rd party developers in my case only get my library in a jar and they can only extend it adding additional classes to it but not modify anything in my jar.

Any suggestions to achieve this, if possible at all? (should be, I am guessing)

here's what I have:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Calculator {

    public double eval(String symbol, double operand1, double operand2) {
        return OperatorRegistry.get(symbol).calculate(operand1, operand2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
        System.out.println(c.eval("+", 3, 9));
        System.out.println(c.eval("-", 13, 9));
    }

}

class OperatorRegistry {
    static HashMap<String, Operator> registry = new HashMap<String, Operator>();
    public static void register(Operator o) {
        System.out.println("Registering: " + o.getSymbol());
        registry.put(o.getSymbol(), o);
    }

    public static Operator get(String c) {
        return registry.get(c);
    }

}

interface Operator {

    public  String getSymbol() ;
    public  double calculate(double a, double b) ;
}


class AddOperator implements Operator{
    static {
        OperatorRegistry.register(new AddOperator());
    }

    public  String getSymbol() {
        return "+";
    }
    public  double calculate(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}



class SubtractOperator implements Operator {
    static {
        OperatorRegistry.register(new SubtractOperator());
    }

    public  String getSymbol() {
        return "-";
    }
    public  double calculate(double a, double b) {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to look at the [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) API. It's already been done.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you need a dynamic Service Locator pattern where you want to execute as and when required even if at runtime. It means, if there is new symbol and there is an implementation for an operator, it should work. I am telling on the base line of your following code.

```
public double eval(String symbol, double operand1, double operand2) {
        return OperatorRegistry.get(symbol).calculate(operand1, operand2);
    }
```

My suggestion will be to maintain a map like this.

```
Map<String (Symbol), OperatorService(Operator Impl)> symbolOpServiceMap
```

There must be load method which will load everytime regardless of whether is a new symbol or not. I will suggest maintain another xml or properties file which will have symbol and OperatorService class implementation. If you distribute your jar, distribute jar along with an externalized xml, json or properties file so that all the operator services will be loaded at runtime. It means, you are providing flexibility that both static and dynamic service will be loaded always and you should be able to execute the following code.

```
OperatorRegistry.get(symbol).calculate(operand1, operand2);
```

To make it more clean, you should have the following structure.

```
public double eval(String symbol, double operand1, double operand2) {
        loadAllOperatorServices();// <= This method will always be invoked and it //will read from xml, json file based upon the number of entries for symbol and //its corresponding implementation. 
        return OperatorRegistry.get(symbol).calculate(operand1, operand2);
    }
```

Hope it may be useful, other senior member can throw more light on this design.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need static initializers. Register 3rd party operators before the use of `Calculator`:

```
// Code of 3rd party developer: 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  OperatorRegistry.register(new MultiplyOperator()); 
  OperatorRegistry.register(new PowerOperator()); 

  Calculator c = new Calculator(); 

  System.out.println(c.eval("+", 3, 9)); 
  System.out.println(c.eval("-", 13, 9)); 
  System.out.println(c.eval("*", 3, 9)); 
  System.out.println(c.eval("^", 13, 9)); 
}
```

And let the Calculator itself register the default operators.

Maybe it's more convenient to move the static `OperatorRegistry.register(Operator)` to the `Calculator`:

```
Calculator.registerOperator(Operator);
```

Then `Calculator` would become:

```
public class Calculator { 
  private static OperatorRegistry operatorRegistry = new OperatorRegistry(); 

  // Register default operators 
  static {
    Calculator.operatorRegistry.register(new SubtractOperator());
    Calculator.operatorRegistry.register(new AddOperator());
  }

  public static registerOperator(Operator operator) {  

    // Delegate call to 'OperatorRegistry'
    Calculator.operatorRegistry.register(operator); 
  } 

  public double eval(String symbol, double operand1, double operand2) { 
    return Calculator.operatorRegistry.get(symbol).calculate(operand1, operand2); 
  }
}

// Code of 3rd party developer: 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  Calculator.registerOperator(new MultiplyOperator()); 
  Calculator.registerOperator(new PowerOperator()); 

  Calculator c = new Calculator(); 

  System.out.println(c.eval("+", 3, 9)); 
  System.out.println(c.eval("-", 13, 9)); 
  System.out.println(c.eval("*", 3, 9)); 
  System.out.println(c.eval("^", 13, 9)); 
}
```